# How to save Non-English characters in an ADF Copy Sink to a CSV dataset

Tags: azure-data-factory

In ADF Copy activity, I am reading data from Databricks Delta tables, columns of which may contain non-english characters. Its reading the data perfectly, as I can see it in preview data. Next, I am saving (sink) the data in a CSV file.

When I open the CSV file, non-english characters are showing as either non readable characters or question marks depends upon what encoding I am using.

When encoding is UTF-8 (default), non-english characters become non-readable.
When encoding is ISO 8859-15, it becomes question marks.

Below is the sample non-english characters
[image]

With encoding UTF-8 (default)

[image]

with encoding  ISO 8859-15

[image]

Any suggestions please

Answer (score 1):

when you create the sink table, you need to define the encode UTF-8 as below:
create table xxxx
(
varchar(500) collate Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8
)